# Strange non-correlation between close/reopen votes and up/downvotes

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-to-close, vote-to-open

[This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/is-infowars-a-credible-source-for-political-news) was closed as offtopic, but received no downvotes. On the other hand, [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24476/what-are-the-downsides-of-requiring-demographic-quotas-in-parliament) received no upvotes, but 4 reopen votes.

Should not be a correlation between downvotes and close votes? Also, why reopen a question that does not deserve upvoting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A close-vote is not a super down-vote. Voting to close simply means that this question either does not belong here or needs some modifications before it can be answered.

You can really like a question, but still think it doesn't belong here. In that case you could upvote, but still vote to close.

You can also think a question shows little research effort is unclear and not useful, but still can't think of a reason why it would not be on-topic. Also, even bad questions might get good answers. In that case you could downvote, but still refuse to vote to close or even vote to reopen.

And then there are questions which are polarizing. Different people can come to very different judgments when looking at some questions. Especially because this website is still plagued by the problem of some people voting on how much they agree with the political opinions of the author instead of the objective quality of their post.

Comment: -1 for plagiarism :)   Seriously, you should link to classical meta posts in that first quote, e.g. https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5479/26771 - there are others around meta